# YouTube API Browser Upload Failing with 500 Internal Error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken used to work just fine but has now stopped working and returns a 500 error everytime, unless the Authorization token has timed out, Then it gets an "Authorize = true" back. So the server is responding and can tell me when my token is no longer any good. Uses OAUth2 and I hve no problem getting a token. Any ideas?

```
** Headers Sent **

[headers] => array(
    [Authorization] => Bearer ********
    [X-GData-Key] => key=*************
    [GData-Version] => 2
    [Content-Type] => application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
)

** Body sent **

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Wildlife</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">Wildlife</media:description>
    <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Travel</media:category>
    <media:keywords>wildlife</media:keywords>
    <media:license type="text/html"/>
  </media:group>
</entry>

** Response data **

Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [x-gdata-user-country] => US
            [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [date] => Sat, 10 Nov 2012 15:45:34 GMT
            [expires] => Sat, 10 Nov 2012 15:45:34 GMT
            [cache-control] => private, max-age=0
            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
            [server] => GSE
        )

    [body] => <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Internal Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Internal Error</H1>
<H2>Error 500</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 500
            [message] => Internal Server Error
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: Found the problem. The empty <media:license type="text/html"/> term in the XML used to be OK. It now causes the Internal Server Error.